# NullPointer error when accessing Hibernate DAO

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hibernate.UserDAO.findAll(UserDAO.java:154)
    at test.main(test.java:12)
```

I am getting this error when trying to do anything with any of my DAOs any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Here's my Data source in my Spring applicationContext.xml file.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        </property>
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://cs180admin.db.5875115.hostedresource.com:3306/cs180admin">
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="xxxxx"></property>
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx"></property>
    </bean>
```

Myeclipse connects to the database fine because I am able to reverse engineer it.

Test.java that I am using to test that throws error.

```
import com.hibernate.UserDAO;


    public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
            System.out.println(dao.findAll());


        }

    }
```

Edit:

```
UserDAO.java
    public List findAll() {
        log.debug("finding all User instances");
        try {
            String queryString = "from User";
        Line 154 -->    return getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString);
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("find all failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

The Line isn't commented out, I just did the arrow to show where the error is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to see the code of your UserDAO class? The NPE is triggered inside that class at the line 154 so the problem is there

Comment: are you calling the DAO directly by creating the object? As far as I know you have to create a bean for your DAO in servlet.xml. If you're not doing this getHibernateTemplate() will return null.
This is the only reason I know that can trigger this exception, otherwise, if getHibernateTemplate() is not returning null you should post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: let me know if that was the problem, in case it works I will really appreciate if you vote up my answer! Thanks

Comment: As @thermz said, you have to create the DAO bean not by yourself, but in the `applicationContext.xml` file, and inject the hibernateTemplate property and add this property in your UserDAO class.